# Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My index.chtml is as below

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I need to add an empty select tag helper `<select asp-for="SimpleViewModel"></select>` to that index.html

`SimpleViewModel` is a ViewModel, which is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MvcMovie.ViewModels
{
    public class SimpleViewModel
    {
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

in order to do so, i will need to add 
@model MvcMovie.ViewModels.SimpleViewModel at the top of index.chtml. Of course, it does not work because Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file

How can i solve the problem by changing the code as less as possible?

ADD MOVIESCONTROLLER CODE

```
// GET: Movies
        public IActionResult Index(string movieGenre, string searchString)
        {
            var GenreQry = from m in _context.Movie
                           orderby m.Genre
                           select m.Genre;
            var GenreList = new List<string>();
            GenreList.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());
            ViewData["movieGenre"] = new SelectList(GenreList);

            var movies = from m in _context.Movie select m;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) {
                movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));

            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre))
            {
                movies = movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre);
            }

            return View(movies);
        }
```

Comment: Introduce a view model with both a `SimpleViewModel` and an `IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view can have only one model.  Currently it's this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>
```

So, presumably, you currently send an `IEnumerable<Movie>` to the view.  If you *don't* and you just want to send a single `SimpleViewModel` to the view, then just change that declaration:

```
@model MvcMovie.ViewModels.SimpleViewModel
```

However, if you want to send *both* to the view, then you need to wrap them in a single view model.  So you might create something like this:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public SimpleViewModel IndexInfo { get; set; }

    // maybe some other logic?
}
```

Then you can use that as your view model:

```
@model MvcMovie.ViewModels.IndexViewModel
```

(Conversely, you could just as easily add an `IEnumerable<Movie>` property to `SimpleViewModel` and use that, if the structure makes sense for what you're building.  It makes no difference to the framework, a class is a class.)

Comment: thanks, if I use IndexViewModel, what do I need to change " @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)" to ?. And what do I need to change "@foreach (var item in Model)" to? Sorry, i am just beginner.

Comment: @K.N.D: Well, any reference to the model would be of type `IndexViewModel`.  So you'd need to access the properties of it, just like you would any properties of any class anywhere in C#.  So something like `foreach (var item in Model)` would become `foreach (var item in Model.Movies)`.  The display names would likely become something like `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movies.First().Genre)`

Comment: I got this error  "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[MvcMovie.Models.Movie]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'MvcMovie.Models.IndexViewModel'.

Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.EnsureCompatible(Object value)"

Comment: I added the code of moviecontroller. I think I need to modify that part also because it is "return View(movies);" now. But I dont know how to correct it. Could you please help? Thanks.

Comment: @K.N.D: You have to pass to the view an object of the type of model it expects.  So if the view expects an `IndexViewModel` then create an instance of that object, set its properties, and pass that to the view.

Comment: I am...sorry I dont know how to do it :(

Comment: @K.N.D: Something like `var model = new IndexViewModel();` would be a good start.  Creating a new instance of an object and setting properties on it is *pretty introductory-level* stuff, to be honest.  You might want to start with some basic C# tutorials.  Basically, your current `movies` variable that you pass to the view is of type `IEnumerable<Movie>`.  But if you change the type of model that the view expects, then you need to send it a variable of the new type instead.

Answer (score 0):

The Only solution i see is of creating a models with at least two properties the List of your movies and the list of your simple model as follows:

```
   public class ComplexViewModel
        {
            public IEnumerable<SimpleViewModel> Simple { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        }

        public class Movie
        {
            //your previous implementation
            public SimpleViewModel simpleViewModel { get; set; }
        }
        public class SimpleViewModel
        {
            public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        }
```

and then in your view you can use

```
@model MvcApplication7.ComplexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Simple);
```